# Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-develpment

Tags: networking, upgrade, proxy

When I tried to update Ubuntu server 18.04 it gives me this error :

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings.
```

I have tried to remove `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm guessing your firewall is blocking the rest. If it can't connect, it can't connect, and that's not really an Ubuntu question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
sudo /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```